# ERROR "The process has been signaled with signal "11" Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, linux, laravel, centos6

I installed WKHTMLTOPDF in my localhost and the system work. But when is uploaded to my Server (CEntos 6 64bits) dont work and laravel sent a message, "ERROR The process has been signaled with signal 11". The path of WKHTMLTOPDF binary file is:

```
'pdf' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary' =>  '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => array(),
),
```

(I installed WKHTMLTOPDF in Linux)

Comment: I found an CentOS doc describing the "Signal 11" error. It doesn't have a fix, but it's at least more information on your issue (which I'm having on a CentOS server, as well):

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/ch14s01s01.html

Comment: For me, this turned out to be an issue with SELINUX on the server machine (it handles security configuration). I don't know the specific change the server admin where I am made, but after he adjusted the SELINUX configuration for my application I stopped seeing this error.

I hope you find the problem! Good luck.